# How to get a script from browser console by making command

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get a command script in the browser, for example I am ona webpage, when I  click a button, I want to have that command script and be able to run it on the console again and give the same result.

How to get that? and will I need to add some variables?

Comment: M.. how about you define a global function and run it in the console? or you could $('#element-selector').click() in console

Comment: What type of command script ?

Answer (score 1):

You can programatically click on the element using [`HTMLElement.click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) or [`$(selector).click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) in jQuery (which will run the script that clicking on the element runs). Just enter `document.querySelector('selector').click()` in the console or `$('selector').click()` (jQuery).

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", function(event){
 console.log("Click");
 //logic here
});
btn.click();//programatically click on element to run click event handler
```

```html
<button id="btn">Button</button>
```

Comment: this is good because it will supply a valid event argument.  I use the global object approach to do adhoc testing of other functions/events not able to be be triggered so easily.

Answer (score 0):

you can attach the function to the the global window object, or another object you attach to the window.  However, if you rely on the event handler's 'event' object, you will have trouble mocking/providing a suitable object.

```
window.myApp = {};

function myButtonClickHandler(event) {
  console.log('my button clicked', event);
}
window.myApp.testClickHandler = myButtonClickHandler;
document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', myButtonClickHandler);
```

now in your javascript console, you can use the testClickHandler function:

```
window.myApp.testClickHandler(); // or just myApp.testClickHandler();
// to mock the event: myApp.testClickHandler({ someProperty: 'someValue'});
```